# In panel dataset, define dummy variable for whether value appears in subsequent period within the same unit

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse

I have a panel dataset defined by districts and time-periods. Within each district/time-period I have a list of people. Here's a simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(district = c("green", "green", "green", "green", 
"green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "blue", "blue"), time = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2000L, 2000L, 1987L, 1987L, 1989L, 1991L, 
1991L), person = c("bill", "jane", "adam", "sue", "bill", "jen", 
"jim", "adam", "jen", "liam", "noah", "pat", "john", "pat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

I want to create a new column, `appears_next_period`, which is a binary variable saying whether or not that person appears in the district in the subsequent time-period. So this is the output I would like in the example:

```
out <- structure(list(district = c("green", "green", "green", "green", 
"green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "blue", "blue"), time = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 2000L, 2000L, 1987L, 1987L, 1989L, 1991L, 
1991L), person = c("bill", "jane", "adam", "sue", "bill", "jen", 
"jim", "adam", "jen", "liam", "noah", "pat", "john", "pat"), 
    appears_next_period = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, NA, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

I'm looking for most efficient way to do this. The best I've come up with so far is a really cumbersome approach using a `left_join`.

```
out_cumbersome <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(time_plus_one = 
           case_when(
             district == "green" & time == 1990 ~ 1995,
             district == "green" & time == 1995 ~ 2000,
             district == "blue" & time == 1987 ~ 1989,
             district == "blue" & time == 1989 ~ 1991,
             TRUE ~ NA_real_
           )) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% mutate(appears_next_period = 1), by = c("district", "time_plus_one" = "time", "person")) %>% 
  mutate(appears_next_period = ifelse(!is.na(time_plus_one) & is.na(appears_next_period), 0, appears_next_period)) %>% 
  select(-time_plus_one)
```

How can I do this better - without having to manually input the next time-period for each district and without having to do the complex `ifelse` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for left joining the table. Grouping our data first according to `district` and `person` and using `lead` we can find whether the person exist in the next period, and then grouping only by `district` we can check whether the specific time is the final period.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  # Does the person exist within the next period, within district?
  group_by(person, district) %>%
  mutate(appears_next_period = lead(time, order_by = time)) %>% 
  mutate(appears_next_period = case_when(is.na(appears_next_period) ~ 0L, 
                                         TRUE ~ 1L)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  # Is the current period within district the final period?
  group_by(district) %>% 
  mutate(appears_next_period = case_when(time == max(time) ~ NA_integer_,
                                         TRUE ~ appears_next_period)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 14 x 4
   district  time person appears_next_period
   <chr>    <int> <chr>                <int>
 1 green     1990 bill                     1
 2 green     1990 jane                     0
 3 green     1990 adam                     1
 4 green     1995 sue                      0
 5 green     1995 bill                     0
 6 green     1995 jen                      1
 7 green     1995 jim                      0
 8 green     2000 adam                    NA
 9 green     2000 jen                     NA
10 blue      1987 liam                     0
11 blue      1987 noah                     0
12 blue      1989 pat                      1
13 blue      1991 john                    NA
14 blue      1991 pat                     NA
```